# Disable a button on another HTML file from a separate JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input-field

This may be a really easy one to answer, but I may be missing something. I've only been into this for a few months.

I am wondering if it is possible to disable a button on a different HTML document based on a click function.

The idea is simple:

HTML1:

```
<input type="submit" class="guest" value="I'm just visiting">
```

HTML2:

```
<input type="submit" class="thisbutton" value="Feature not for guests">
```

JS:

```
$('.guest').click(function() {
        $('.thisbutton').prop('disabled', true); //this is on another file
        $('.thisbutton').css('background-color', 'grey');
    });
```

Some ideas:

With a cookie? With a link in the header?
The cookie is one idea but it would be easy to delete.

Thanks for your time to look at this!

Comment: You can use session/localStorage to save the state and decide not to enable it on the other page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use local storage for that by saving an entry for the guest when the user clicks on `.guest` button in the HTML1 page then gets the entry in the other page HTML2 in the ready function to disable the `thisbutton`.

**HTML 1:**

```
// set the item in localStorage on click
$('.guest').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('guest', true);
});
```

**HTML 2 :**

```
$(function(){
    // get the item 
    if ( localStorage.getItem('guest') !== null ) {
        $('.thisbutton').prop('disabled', true);
        $('.thisbutton').css('background-color', 'grey');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I was able to change it to be as follows, as your answer would leave the button disabled if I left and returned as a registered user:                                   
  `if ( localStorage.guest != 'false' ) {
        $('.thisbutton').prop('disabled', true);
        $('.thisbutton').css('background-color', 'grey');
    }`